# JQuery Sortable - disable "update" event from within the "receive" event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a sortable ordered list and making updates to a database based on:

1. Dragging a new item to the list, calls the "receive" event to do a db insert
2. Sorting the list, updates the display order in the database.

Now since the "update" and "receive" events are both part of sortable, and each is set to perform an ajax post (asynchronously), I can't control the order of these events. I need the "receive" event to fire and complete BEFORE the "update" event.

My thought was to .unbind the update event from inside the receive event and then rebind or manually call the update event, but I can't get it to work.

I am a newbie at jquery, so any help is much appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance,
Chad

```
    $("#myMovieListItems").sortable({
            receive: OnReceive,
            update: OnSortableUpdate,
            placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
            containment: 'document',
            revert: true
        });
function OnReceive(event, ui) {
            //Disable the update event and manually call it on success of this event
            $("#myMovieListItems").unbind("update");

            //Set ID of new list element with it's original value
            var newItem = $(this).data().sortable.currentItem;
            newItem.attr('id', $(ui.sender).attr('id'));

            //Get Data to pass to AJAX method
            droppedID = newItem.attr('id');
            droppedName = $.trim(newItem.first().contents().filter(function () {
                return this.nodeType == 3;
            }).text());

            messageContainer.html(progressMessage);
            source = "Facebook";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: GetSiteRoot() + 'DesktopModules/Incite/MovieRotation/Handlers/Sortable.asmx/InsertMovie',
                data: '{strMovieName: \'' + droppedName + '\', intMovieListID: \'' + movieListID + '\', strSource: \'' + source + '\', strSourceID: \'' + droppedID + '\'}',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: OnAddMovieSuccess,
                error: OnSortableUpdateError
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i was just having this same problem with sortable, ended up using debounce from underscore.js

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

It can wrap event handlers in a timer, for instances where you may have more then one event fired but only want to call a handler once.  For sortable, i trigger a custom event on both receive and update, then there is a debounced handler that listens for that, and with timing, makes sure it's only called once when the last event is received.